# Once poisoned does it matter if I stay in poison clouds?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Whenever a thin man gobs phlegm all over one of my guys I always move him away next turn. But I've been wondering about whether I need to: after all he's already poisoned.

Do poison effects stack? Does the poison expire after a number of turns and staying in the cloud renews this count? Is there something else I'm not thinking of?

Comment: fwiw poison wears off after 3 turns

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are poisoned and run through a poison cloud, the poison counter resets.

You will get the "Poisoned" popup again, even though you are already poisoned.

Comment: ah ok, so if you move out next turn you take 3 ticks of damage, and if you stay put you take 3 + the duration of the cloud? (How long does the cloud last?)

Comment: @Ian I believe the cloud stays around for one turn after it appears, same as the smoke grenade. If you're fighting Thin Men, however, you're rarely dealing with only one cloud, however!

Comment: So based on that there is no need to move out of the cloud if you are planning to cure the poison anyway.

Comment: @SimonWaldman Yes, as long as you don't try to cure the poison while still in the cloud. (Not sure what happens in that case)

Comment: @RavenDreamer hmm, interesting question. If you were to cure the poison and then move out of the cloud on the same turn, would you get poisoned again? Logically one probably should, but I've never tested.

Comment: Now accepting this answer as I've played a bunch more and seen for myself: **if I leave the cloud immediately I take 3 damage total. If I sit in it until it dissipates I take 4 damage total.** I too have never tried healing whilst in a poison cloud.

Comment: I recently checked this. If you heal while inside the poison cloud, you will not suffer poison damage from that cloud. You need to leave it (first move) and then re-enter it to get poisoned once again.
Apparently, poison is applied when unit crosses the boundary between "poison free" space and the poison cloud. It is also applied when unit crosses boundary between two adjacent poison clouds (i.e. steps from one into another cloud). When Thin Man casts poison on any unit, it does two things: applies poison to the enemy "manually" and creates a poison cloud since there was no boundary crossing.